# Why CSS Media Query doesn't work on mobile device but yes on Google Chrome device emulator?

Tags: css, mpmediaquery

As from the title, I don't understand why the media query works on emulator device on Google Chrome and it doesn't work on a real mobile device.

Html meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=max-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Css:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:640px) and (max-device-width:767px){...}
```

Actually I've set up the min and max resolutions from 640/768/850/1024 for mobile devices screen resolution, but it seems be an error, cause .... I don't understand yet

Comment: Don't do this `maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"` it's not recommended and provides a very poor user experience.

Comment: But surely by removing that it will fail to view properly on a mobile device?

Answer (score 3):

You should apply device width in meta viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS should be like the following and check:

```
@media screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:767px){...}
```