# Materializecss mobile version

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, material-design, materialize

I'm using [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com) and angularjs for my website. The problem is quite interesting:

When i use Chrome and resize my website, everything stays responsive (not perfectly tough). But when i use the Chrome Emulation tool (with Apple iPhone 6) its not responsive anymore.

Have a look at the screenshots:

[image: Chrome emulation tool Apple iPhone 6]

[image: Chrome with the same with as Apple iPhone6]

So you can see the different scale.

You can have a look at it at [zencubes.io](https://zencubes.io)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of your problem sounds like it's been answered here previously at Stackoverflow here, where it works in the device emulator in Chrome but not on the actual device itself.

[Why CSS Media Query doesn't work on mobile device but yes on Google Chrome device emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329258/why-css-media-query-doesnt-work-on-mobile-device-but-yes-on-google-chrome-devic)

Have you checked your Viewport meta tag settings, in particular the width attribute?